# How to change Color of MetroWindow Minimize/Maximise/Close Buttons (Font)?

Tags: c#, xaml, mahapps.metro

How to change the color of the Mahapps.Metro MetroWindow Minimize/Maximise/Close Buttons (Font) to white?

Comment: Been awhile but if I recall right there's a resource dictionary called Icons.xaml (or similar) that has the Path data for those glyphs where you'd just change the Fill/Stroke

Comment: that did the trick. thx. also the CleanWindow style (where the MetroWindow titlebar has no special accent colour) has dark buttons instead instead of the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how to achive this when taking a look into the Dark VS Style and the Clean Style of Mahapps.Metro.